# Get more accurate GPS SNR/PNR/Elevation/Azimuth precision

Tags: android

Right now I am using a `gpsStatus` to get a list of satellites from the android SDK.  I am retrieving the variables with the following methods:

```
float az = item.getAzimuth();
float el = item.getElevation();
int p = item.getPrn();
float s = item.getSnr();
```

So far I am getting values of only 1 point in precision, mostly .0, so for instance:

(173.0, 47.0, 74, 30.0)  For the floating point numbers is there anyway to get more precision?  I was able to use a `Criteria` to get more precision out of the Accuracy, Latitude, and Longitude.  I need to try and get as precise data as possible for the satellite information too.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused by your comment that you used a Criteria to get more precision out of Accuracy, Latitude, and Longitude. getLatitude() and getLongitude() will always return double precision variables. getAccuracy() will always return a single precision variable. It is true that a Criteria could require the LocationManager to return more accurate GPS results, but the variables will still have the same precision.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure about this, but I believe that most (if not all) GPS receivers will only output azimuth and elevation data to the nearest degree. Similarly, SNR values are only given to the nearest integer (perhaps professional-grade receivers will give more precise SNR measurements, but I don't any smartphone-based receiver would do so.). PRNs are, of course, only integer values.

So I'm afraid that the answer to your question (if I'm correct about GPS receivers) is that it is not possible to get more accurate azimuth, elevation, and SNR info using any Android API, since the API just retrieves whatever is output by the receiver.

The only possibility I can think of to get more accurate azimuth and elevation values would be to retrieve the GPS satellite almanac from some online source, and then calculate the expected azimuth and elevation at your current location using formulae of geodesy. In other words, a not so easy task...

By the way, you mention that the output is "**mostly** .0", but I think if you go back and check, all values are ending in .0.